# SQL Server query SELECT only the latest message

Tags: sql-server

```
 id|   from   | to      |message   |datetime             |
---| ---------|---------|----------|---------------------|
 1 | john     | peter   |Hi        |2016-01-01 12:00:00  |
 2 | peter    | john    |What's up |2016-01-01 12:01:00  |
 3 | jack     | jason   |Hey       |2016-01-02 12:00:00  |
 4 | jason    | jack    |Hi        |2016-01-01 12:01:00  |
```

Let's say I have a table like this, can you guys give me the idea how to write a SQL Server query to select only the latest message between two users.

The expected result for the table above should be select only id 2 and 3

Comment: For jason and jack, it should be `id = 3`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan No, I only want the latest message, id = 4 is the message with the latest datetime.

Comment: Yeah, but 2016-01-02 > 2016-01-01. Unless it's a typo.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Oh yeah, sorry, it's a typo, I will edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                            PARTITION BY 
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN [from] >= [to] THEN [from]
                                    ELSE [to]
                                END,
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN [from] >= [to] THEN [to]
                                    ELSE [from]
                                END
                            ORDER BY datetime DESC
                          )
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id
```

To achieve the proper grouping, I arrange the `PARTITION BY` alphabetically, meaning the first column in the `PARTITION` will be the first from `from` and `to` alphabetically, and the second column will be the last.

[**Try it here.**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/427845)

Comment: Is this a stored procedure?

Comment: It is not a stored proc.  It is a query which uses common tables expressions and analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ANSI-92 compliant solution if you do not wish to use Felix's solution (which uses SQL Server `ROW_NUMBER`):

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.v1 AS from, t.v2 AS to, MAX(t.datetime) AS maxTime
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CASE WHEN from < to THEN from ELSE to END AS v1,
               CASE WHEN from < to THEN to ELSE from END AS v2,
               datetime
        FROM messages
    ) t
    GROUP BY t.v1, t.v2
) m2
ON ((m1.from = m2.from AND m1.to = m2.to) OR (m1.from = m2.to AND m1.to = m2.from))
    AND m1.datetime = m2.maxTime
```

Comment: The concept here is similar with the answer of @Felix Pamittan right?

Comment: The trick for handling two way conversations as being the same is similar.  The execution plan is a bit different.